# Can you do a set.State and add the Element to the top of the Array?

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I've been wondering if you could add a new Element with the set.State function, but instead of adding it to the last index, you add it as the first element.

For Example we have:

```
    data: {
    "0": "name1",
    "1": "name2",
    "2": "name3"
    }
```

And I want to add an Element to the top with set.State so it looks like this:

```
data: {
"0": "name4",
"1": "name1",
"2": "name2",
"3": "name3"
}
```

Any help would be appreciated since I've been searching for a solution for the past 2 hours.

Thanks :)))

Answer (score 1):

Try with unshift and spread operator ( ES6 ):

```
var newData = ...this.state.data; // Add name4 to first position in array
newData.unshift("name4");
this.setState({data: newData}); // update state
```

Or with one-line:

```
this.setState({data: ["name4", ...this.state.data]});
```

Sorry for possible syntax errors, did not test this code.

Comment: Thanks fro your help. It didn't quite work with the unshift. But I solved my Problem by creating a new State where I saved my old State but just backwards. Then I've added the new Data and flipped it again to my actual State.
Thanks for your time, appreciate it :)